# Nested HttpWebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, httprequest

[HTTPWEBREQUEST 1]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEWHlNApMtROuP_0Q

[HTTPWEBREQUEST 2]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEXlHjqHdho3lUjfw

When I am trying to call withing main for second time a HttpWebRequest1 and the nested HttpWebRequest2, it runs fine. But on the second run of the nested HttpWebRequest2 I get an exception on THIS line(System.IO.StreamReader sr2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(s2)) on its second run.
Exception:> "Message = "Stream was not readable."

```
try
            {
                HttpWebRequest WebRequestObjectCards = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.ucy.ac.cy/api/v1/cards?status=Valid&");
                HttpWebRequest WebRequestObjectUsers = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.ucy.ac.cy/api/v1/users/" + ucy_id);


                if (WebRequestObjectCards != null && WebRequestObjectUsers != null)
                {
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Method = "GET";
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Timeout = 12000;
                    WebRequestObjectCards.ContentType = "application/json";
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                    WebRequestObjectCards.KeepAlive = true;

                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Method = "GET";
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Timeout = 12000;
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.ContentType = "application/json";
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.KeepAlive = true;

                    using (System.IO.Stream s = WebRequestObjectCards.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                        {
                            var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647
                            Students UCYstudents = serializer.Deserialize<Students>(jsonResponse);

                            //String to be added in csv
                            var csv = new StringBuilder();

                            //prepare CSV Header
                            newLine = string.Format("***StartOfFile***");
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                            newLine = string.Format("ID; FirstName; LastName; RFIDUID; PrintedCardNumber; ValidUntil; Enabled; email; group ");
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);

                            //deserialize JSON to CSV
                            foreach (var item in UCYstudents.data)
                            {
                                if (item.ucy_id != null)
                                {
                                    ucy_id = item.ucy_id;// used as parameter for WebRequestObjectUsers
                                    ID = item.ucy_id.ToString().TrimStart('0');
                                    RFIDUID = item.card_number.ToString().TrimStart('0');
                                    PrintedCardNumber = item.card_number.ToString().TrimStart('0');

                                    if (item.expiration_date != null)
                                    {
                                        ValidUntil = item.expiration_date.ToString().Replace("-30","-01");

                                        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ValidUntil);
                                        ValidUntil = ("" + dt.Day + "." + dt.Month + "." + dt.Year);

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ValidUntil = "";
                                    }

                                    Enabled = "TRUE";

                                    //Getting response from WebRequestObjectUsers
                                  using (System.IO.Stream s2 = WebRequestObjectUsers.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                                    {
                                        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(s2))
                                        {

                                            serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                                            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647
                                            jsonResponse = sr2.ReadToEnd();
                                            Users UCYUser = serializer.Deserialize<Users>(jsonResponse);

                                            FirstName = UCYUser.data.name_en.ToString();
                                            LastName = UCYUser.data.surname_en.ToString();
                                            email = UCYUser.data.mail.ToString();
                                            group = "1";

                                            //Write Fields to CSV File
                                            newLine = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8}", ID, FirstName, LastName, RFIDUID, PrintedCardNumber, ValidUntil, Enabled, email, group);
                                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                                    ID = "";
                                    FirstName = "";
                                    LastName = "";
                                    RFIDUID = "";
                                    PrintedCardNumber = "";
                                    ValidUntil = "";
                                    email = "";
                                    group = "";

                                            sr2.Close();


                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }



                            File.WriteAllText(@".\export.csv", csv.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: At first glance, your code looks good. Can you test that token in another program, requesting the same endpoint? Maybe Postman? (https://www.getpostman.com/) Have you double checked that you are using the same token from the first request to the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two `HttpWebRequest` objects you create are different instances of the class; you don't need to close or reset one while using the other.

If the API is following conventions, then the `401` error means exactly what the message says: the server doesn't think the second request is authorized to access that endpoint. Maybe the server has different permissions required to get the list of users. The server identifies the request and permissions through the `Authorization: Bearer` token that you are sending. Look at other ways to test that token and request data from that endpoint.

Comment: I fixed authorization problem. New problem appears now."Message = "Stream was not readable." I revised my Post.

Comment: @Pavlosh - For a new question, you should post a new question, not revise an older one. This will help everyone in a few ways: your new question will get more attention, and my answer (above) won't be for a question that no longer exists.Stack Overflow is meant to help other people with the same questions in the future, that's why voting on quality questions and answers plays a big part.